# React, Redux, Logout action doesn't update components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have this: https://codesandbox.io/s/j3llymyxqw

And I can't explain why it is not working on Logout.

I followed tutorial to learn react-redux way of doing this.

Why it is not working?

*authReducers.js*:

```
import {
  AUTHENTICATED,
  UNAUTHENTICATED,
  AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
} from "../actions/actionTypes";

export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AUTHENTICATED:
      return { ...state, authenticated: true };

    case UNAUTHENTICATED:
      return { ...state, authenticated: false };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

*authActions.js*:

```
import * as actionTypes from "./actionTypes";

export function loginAction(history) {
  return async dispatch => {
    const timeout = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
    await timeout(1000);
    ....
    dispatch({ type: actionTypes.AUTHENTICATED });
  };
}

export function logoutAction(history) {
  ...
  return { type: actionTypes.UNAUTHENTICATED };
}
```

Comment: "It's not working" is not very helpful. What specifically do you expect to happen, and what specifically is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

You were not passing the `logoutAction` to `connect()` and you should have called it `this.props.logoutAction()`

Your NavBar should look like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

import { logoutAction } from "./actions/authActions";

class Navbar extends Component {

  onLogout = () => {
    this.props.logoutAction(this.props.history)
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.authenticated) {
      return (
        <div>
          <div>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            {" | "}
            <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
            {" | "}
            <NavLink to="/faq">Faq</NavLink>
            {" | "}
            <button onClick={this.onLogout}>
              Sign out
            </button>
          </div>
          <br />
          <br />
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <NavLink to="/login">Log in</NavLink>
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  authenticated: state.auth.authenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  logoutAction
})(Navbar);
```

Comment: Did you mean to post this on another question?

Comment: It works good Alexander. Can you explain why it is working now? Please...

Comment: @JohnSam Edited

Comment: Ok, but why I need `onLogout` instead of simply `() => {
    this.props.logoutAction(this.props.history)` in code?

Comment: @JohnSam You can do it both ways, I simply prefer `onLogout`

Comment: Ok. My error was `this.props.logoutAction`. Thanks a lot.